# Crear una BD Local en xamarin form utilizando SQLite y Linq para un modelo obtenido desde un API Service

Tags: android-sqlite, xamarin.forms, linq-to-sql

Saludos,

Necesito que una aplicación móvil que obtiene unos datos desde un API Service funcione también offline, para esto debo crear una tabla local que almacene el modelo con la información que traigo desde el API cuando haya conexión a internet, el modelo es el siguiente:

```
public class Country
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> topLevelDomain { get; set; }
    public string alpha2Code { get; set; }
    public string alpha3Code { get; set; }
    public List<string> callingCodes { get; set; }
    public string capital { get; set; }
    public List<string> altSpellings { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string subregion { get; set; }
    public long population { get; set; }
    public List<double> latlng { get; set; }
    public string demonym { get; set; }
    public double? area { get; set; }
    public List<string> timezones { get; set; }
    public List<string> borders { get; set; }
    public string nativeName { get; set; }
    public string numericCode { get; set; }
    public List<Currency> currencies { get; set; }
    public List<Language> languages { get; set; }
    public Translations translations { get; set; }
    public string flag { get; set; }
    public List<RegionalBloc> regionalBlocs { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return CountryId;
    }
}
```

Para insertar, actualizar y eliminar registros utilizo la siguiente clase:

```
public class DataService
{
    public bool DeleteAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            using (var da = new DataAccess())
            {
                var oldRecords = da.GetList<T>(false);
                foreach (var oldRecord in oldRecords)
                {
                    da.Delete(oldRecord);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public T DeleteAllAndInsert<T>(T model) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            using (var da = new DataAccess())
            {
                var oldRecords = da.GetList<T>(false);
                foreach (var oldRecord in oldRecords)
                {
                    da.Delete(oldRecord);
                }

                da.Insert(model);

                return model;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return model;
        }
    }

    public T InsertOrUpdate<T>(T model) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            using (var da = new DataAccess())
            {
                var oldRecord = da.Find<T>(model.GetHashCode(), false);
                if (oldRecord != null)
                {
                    da.Update(model);
                }
                else
                {
                    da.Insert(model);
                }

                return model;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            return model;
        }
    }

    public T Insert<T>(T model)
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            da.Insert(model);
            return model;
        }
    }

    public T Find<T>(int pk, bool withChildren) where T : class
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            return da.Find<T>(pk, withChildren);
        }
    }

    public T First<T>(bool withChildren) where T : class
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            return da.GetList<T>(withChildren).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    public List<T> Get<T>(bool withChildren) where T : class
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            return da.GetList<T>(withChildren).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Update<T>(T model)
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            da.Update(model);
        }
    }

    public void Delete<T>(T model)
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            da.Delete(model);
        }
    }

    public void Save<T>(List<T> list) where T : class
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {
            foreach (var record in list)
            {
                InsertOrUpdate(record);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando intento crear el almacenamiento local con el siguiente código:

```
       var url = Application.Current.Resources["URLAPI"].ToString();

        var response = await apiService.GetList<Country>(
            url,
            "/rest/v2/all");
       // Storage data local
        countries = (List<Country>)response.Result;
        dataService.DeleteAll<Country>();
        dataService.Save(countries);
```

Ocurre una excepción al llamar los métodos dataService.DeleteAll y dataService.Save debido a que el modelo Country tiene propiedades que son List y una que es un objeto tipo Translations, pero no puedo modificar el modelo porque así están definidas estas propiedades en el API Service desde el cual recibo la información, ¿qué puedo hacer para hacerle un Cast a estas propiedades en el modelo o como puedo solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 2 alternativas con las que puedes resolver tu problema.

1. Ignora las propiedades tipo Lista que no son soportadas por SQLite.Solo marca esas propiedades con **`[Ignore]`** si no son importantes.
2. Si necesitas las propiedades, crea otro modelo para persistir el objeto del servicio y convierte de ida y vuelta. Puedes guardar las listas en la tabla como string si la serializas a **JSON** primero, por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jesús, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta. Como necesitaba las propiedades me decanté por la segunda alternativa, creé otro modelo y utilicé la función JsonConvert.SerializeObject para convertir la información del objeto que devolvía el servicio en un String para poder guardarla en la tabla de este nuevo modelo y cuando necesito consumir los datos locales convierto nuevamente el String en un objeto utilizando JsonConvert.DeserializeObject.